# Get SQLite user version via JDBC connection

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm using JDBC to connect to a SQLite database:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/test.db");
```

Now my problem is that I'm not able to get the user version. I know that I can use PRAGMA but if I execute:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("PRAGMA user_version;");
```

then the retrieved result set will be closed (no data sets found).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you have problem in code not described in question because this snippet can set and get `user_version` without problem:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");

        try(Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
            statement.execute("PRAGMA user_version = 10;");
        }

        try(Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
            try(ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("PRAGMA user_version;")) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sqlite adapter:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.15.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You're right - it was my mistake. I get the version in a method and in this method I have a try..finally which closes the statement. I overlooked the strong reference between Statement and ResultSet.